# self join table to get hierarchy for specific root node

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using postgresql db and i want to use sql get the children of the root node '0' (including the root node) of the table below. Most examples online show how to get all the hierarchies (thats easy with self-join).

However i want to inform the root (say '0') and then only get that hierarchy. My table below has 2 hierarchies (root entries '0' and 'a').

**Data**

| Id | ParentId |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | null |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| a | null |
| b | a |

**Expected result**

| Id | ParentId |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | null |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: Can you clarify what the criteria for your filtering is? You said you want all of the children of the root node (0) but your expected result includes the root node and all n-children.

And can you share some sql that hasn't worked and explain why it hasn't worked for your case? Based on what you said, this example should suffice for building out hierarchy and you can filter afterwards: https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-query-hierarchical-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) to do to this. They are complicated to wrap your head around, but they are very common solution for a parent/child hierarchy table.

In your case it would look something like:

```
WITH recCTE AS 
(
   /* Here we select the starting point for the recursion */
   SELECT Id, ParentId FROM yourtable WHERE Id = 0
   UNION ALL
   /* Here we select how the recursive result set joins to 
    * to the original table
    * 
    * This will run over and over again until the join fails
    * appending records to the recCTE result set as it goes.
    */
   SELECT 
      yourtable.Id,
      yourtable.ParentId
   FROM recCTE
      INNER JOIN yourtable 
          ON recCTE.Id = yourtable.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic recursive CTE will produce the result you want. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select * from t where id = 0
 union all
  select t.* from n join t on t.parentid = n.id
)
select * from n
```